# Custom Columns Don't Display Anything

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-hook

I have added a new column to a custom post type to display the post's ID. This works for the WordPress core post type, but not for my custom post type. I have tried using the manage_{post_type}_custom_column hook and just applying it to all posts, but neither works.

It DOES add the custom column headers, but I can't populate them with anything at all when viewing the custom post type.

[This is what it looks like when viewing the custom post type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVZmr.png)
and
[this is what it looks like when viewing a regular core post.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPnCP.png)

```
//  Add post ID column to use an order ID in all posts view.

add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'oms_order_id_header');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'oms_order_id_column', 10, 2);

function oms_order_id_header($columns) {
    //Remove title column
    //unset($columns['title']);
    //Add new columns
    $columns['order_id_header'] = 'Order ID';
    $columns['customer_header'] = 'Customer';
    $columns['author']          = 'Owner';    

    return $columns;
}

function oms_order_id_column( $column, $post_id ) {
        if ($column == 'order_id_header') {
            echo $post_id;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This turned out to be an issue with the post type being set to hierarchical. Hierarchical post types need to be targeted by a different action hook than the one used here.

Instead of [manage_posts_custom_column](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column), hierarchical post types need to use [manage_pages_custom_column](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_pages_custom_column).

Answer (score 0):

I just tried you code and it seems to be working perfect on my WordPress installation in both cases: Custom Post and Post.

Maybe your error is happening because your posts are drafts? I don't think so but maybe. (I tried your code also with drafts on my installation and it worked). Here is the screenshot: [image: screenshot]

Try printing "hello world" instead of the $post_id to check if it prints in all cases.